# List out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7

im trying to do letter sorting according to this example :

Input:

```
people enjoy programming
```

Output:

```
[(set(['e', 'o']), set(['l']), set(['p'])), 
(set(['e', 'o']), set(['j']), set(['n', 'y'])), 
(set(['o', 'a', 'i']), set(['g', 'm']), set(['p', 'r', 'n']))]
```

So here is my code :

```
lista=[[[0],[0],[0]],[[0],[0],[0]],[[0],[0],[0]]]
x=raw_input('please enter 3 words: ')
words=x.split()
if len(words)!=3:
    print('error!!! enter 3 words ')
else:
    i=0
    c=0
    while i<3:
        for m in range(len(words[i])):
           if words[i][m] in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
                       lista.insert([i][0][c],words[i][m])
                       lista.insert([i][0][-1],0)
                       c=c+1
           elif words[i][m] in ['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m']:
                       lista.insert([i][1][c],words[i][m])
                       lista.insert([i][1][-1],0)
                       c=c+1
           else:
                       lista.insert([i][2][c],words[i][m])
                       lista.insert([i][2][-1],0)
                       c=c+1
        i=i+1
    lista=(set(lista[1][1],lista[1][2],lista[1][3],lista[2][1],lista[2][2],lista[2][3],lista[3][1],lista[3][2],lista[3][3]))
    lista=(tuple(lista[1],lista[2],lista[3]))
    print lista
```

And when i try to run it i get this error :

> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Python27/ex7.py", line 22, in 
> >         lista.insert([i][2][c],words[i][m]) IndexError: list index out of range

Someone see what i did wrong?

Comment: Your suggested output seems wrong to me. There is no `n` in the sets for `enjoy`. Also, on what basis are you grouping the consonants?

Comment: Your's is a 3d array and you are using 4 indices to access it

Comment: @mu無 I think I put the `'n'` where it belongs.

Comment: please explain how the sorting is done.

Comment: The way I understand the sorting is: vowels first, then `b` to `m` consonants, then `n` to `z` consonants.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the line `lista.insert([i][1][c],words[i][m])` (and the similar lines with other indexes) do what you seem to be intending. Rather than inserting `words[i][m]` into `lista[i][1][c]`, you're getting an error when trying to evaluate `[i][1][c]`. That subexpression creates an one element list (`[i]`, then tries to access the value at index `1`, which doesn't work.

I think you may want to use something like `lista[i][1].append(words[i][m])`.

However, it would be much easier if you directly iterated over your lists and strings, rather than using `range`s and indexing:

```
output = []

for word in words:
    vowels = set()
    consonants1 = set()
    consonants2 = set()

    for character in word:
        if character in "aeiou":
            vowels.add(character)
        elif character in "bcdfghjklm":
            consonants1.add(character)
        else:
            consonants2.add(character)

    output.append([vowels, consonants1, consonants2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words = []
output = []
desired_output = [(set(['e', 'o']), set(['l']), set(['p'])), (set(['e', 'o']), set(['j']), set(['n', 'y'])),
                  (set(['o', 'a', 'i']), set(['g', 'm']), set(['p', 'r', 'n']))]

while True:
    # words = raw_input('please enter 3 words: ').split()
    words = "people enjoy programming".split()
    if len(words) != 3:
        print('error!!! enter 3 words ')
    else:
        break

for word in words:
    vow = set()
    con1 = set()
    con2 = set()
    for char in word:
        if char in "aeiou":
            vow.add(char)
        elif char in "bcdfghjklm":
            con1.add(char)
        else:
            con2.add(char)
    output.append([vow, con1, con2])

print output
print desired_output
```

Output:

```
[[set(['e', 'o']), set(['l']), set(['p'])], [set(['e', 'o']), set(['j']), set(['y', 'n'])], [set(['a', 'i', 'o']), set(['m', 'g']), set(['p', 'r', 'n'])]]
[(set(['e', 'o']), set(['l']), set(['p'])), (set(['e', 'o']), set(['j']), set(['y', 'n'])), (set(['a', 'i', 'o']), set(['m', 'g']), set(['p', 'r', 'n']))]
```

Replace the `words = "people enjoy programming".split()` for the one above it to make it interactive.

Your use of range and index to access items is very common among anyone who already had a past programming experience(perhaps C++?), in Python most of the things are iterable. You can use a for loop over a list, and it will return each item, you can iterate over a string and it will return each character.